# Rails4 : model validates "format with" regex for slug column

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, slug

My model has slug with friendly ID gem, and sometimes user inputs only-digit slug and has problem with accessing pages.
Then I want to change model validation except only-digit and some special chars.

Here is the current model validates

```
validates :slug, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }, uniqueness: true,
        format: {with: /\A[^\s!#$%^&*()（）=+;:'"\[\]\{\}|\\\/<>?,]+\z/, message: :invalid_slug}
```

How can I add here??

EXAMPLE:

Current:

```
'123' => valid
'abc' => valid
'adb?&' => invalid
```

New:

```
'123' => invalid
'abc' => valid
'adb?&' => invalid
```

cheers

Comment: Do you want to have all special characters(except ? and &) in slug or just underscore and hyphen?

Comment: How do you generate the slug from the input? Why don't you handle that cases when you generate the slug?

Comment: So, just add the digits to the negated character class: `/\A[^0-9\s!#$%^&*()（）=+;:'"\[\]\{\}|\\\/<>?,]+\z/` - isn't that what you need? Or do you want to allow digits + something else and want to disallow numeric-only slugs? Then use `/\A(?!\d+\z)[^\s!#$%^&*()（）=+;:'"\[\]\{\}|\\\/<>?,]+\z/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current regex:

```
/\A[^\s!#$%^&*()（）=+;:'"\[\]\{\}|\\\/<>?,]+\z/
```

Matches any string that only contains 1+ symbols other than those specified in the *negated character class* `[^...]`. So, since there are no digits, the digits are allowed in the string, and there can be 1+ digits, and the regex will match that numeric-only slug.

To restrict this pattern to exclude matching numeric-only slugs, just add a `(?!\d+\z)` lookahead right after the `\A` anchor:

```
/\A(?!\d+\z)[^\s!#$%^&*()（）=+;:'"\[\]\{\}|\\\/<>?,]+\z/
   ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA3mT5/1) (multiline, thus, using `^` / `$` anchors, you need to use `\A` and `\z` in ROR)

This lookahead will be executed once at the beginning of the string, and will return false when it asserts (=matches) only digits (1 or more) up to the end of the string.